# AngularJS: ng-placeholder not working

Tags: html, angularjs, placeholder

I have the following input html element that I want to change the placeholder of depending on what is being held in my user model.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" name="Username" data-ng-model="user.Username" required="" ng-placeholder="{{user.AdAccount ? 'Username' : 'Ad Login'}}">
```

I even tried this method that is said to have worked in previous versions of angular, but no success.

```
ng-placeholder="user.AdAccount == true && 'Username' || 'AD Login'"
```

At the moment my placeholder just appears completely blank. I also know that AdAccount is holding true/false correctly because it is being used elsewhere on the form with ng-show.

Comment: which version of Angular you are using

Comment: Have you tried the line you are using now without the {{}}?

Comment: Hi, I am using 1.3.15, which judging by an answer i saw elsewhere on here should be fine? And yes @Guinn I have tried it without the curly braces and it made no difference.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I don't think there's any ngPlaceholder directive. Try changing your code to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" name="Username" data-ng-model="user.Username" required="" placeholder="{{user.AdAccount ? 'Username' : 'Ad Login'}}" />
```

That is, change `ng-placeholder`into just `placeholder`, and everything should work fine.

(Note also the self-closing slash if you need to conform to valid XHTML.)

Comment: I actually wasn't aware these conditional statements would work outside of the ng- directives. Thanks!

Comment: {{ ... }} makes angular evaluate any given expression within the curly braces - try just {{ 2 + 2 }} or whatever, and you'll see. If you do use directives, you don't need the curlies.

Comment: Yeah seems obvious now you say it -_-

Comment: **Please not that this approach may not work in internet explorer.** Cf. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie
You probably want to use `ng-attr-placeholder` instead.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" name="Username" data-ng-model="user.Username" required="" ng-attr-placeholder="{{user.AdAccount ? 'Username' : 'Ad Login'}}">
```

`ng-attr-` will work with any HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{doctorname ? doctorname : 'Dr. your name'}}"
       class="editable-class" ng-model="doctor.name" readonly/>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.doctorname = $scope.doctorinfo.name;
```