# AngularJS - placeholder issues in Select

Tags: angularjs

Good morning, I have a problem with a placeholder not functioning. Having researched SO for similar problems, got this one that describes a pretty similar issue, but no solutions for my problems:

[AngularJS: ng-placeholder not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573999/angularjs-ng-placeholder-not-working)

I have a select field:

```
  <select ng-model="form.experience"
          name="experience"
          ng-options="e for e in experience"
          class="form-control"
          data-placeholder="Experience"
          tabindex="11"
          required=""/>
```

In controller I have:

```
$scope.experience = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Then, in browser I see the following. My understanding is that it should already be working, however the placeholder is not displayed in the select field. Would appreciate some help as I am obviously missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

placeholder wont work in select while using ng-options

two solution :

```
<select ng-model="form.experience"
      name="experience">
    <option >Experience</option>
    <option ng-repeat="e in experience"></option>
 </select>
```

second is :

```
$scope.experience = ['Experience',1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$scope.form.experience = 'Experience';

  <select ng-model="form.experience"
      name="experience"
      ng-options="e for e in experience"
      class="form-control"
      data-placeholder="Experience"
      tabindex="11"
      required=""/>
```

Comment: Thank you. So that is the problem, I attempted using placeholder in select while using ng-options, good to know. Marking as approved